# getting yml syntax highlighting in textmate2

Tags: syntax-highlighting, bundle, textmate-2

I ignored the prompt of textmate2 to to associate yml files with yml by mistake, and instead chose .txt. the result is no syntax highlighting and i can't figure out how to fix it.

Installing and activating the YML bundle doesn't help. is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need remove Textmate preferences and reinstall it. If you are using OSX find Library folder and search "textmate" and remove all files you find there, then remove textmate app normally from Application folder and install textmate again from its website. 
You will see again recommendation for .yml file when you open a .yml file for the first time and choose the option "see as YAML file". It  hopefully solve the problem.

Comment: Hi thank you for the help, can you give me a better idea of what the preferences file is called? There are a lot of files, some of which may not be textmate related...

Comment: This definitely pointed me in the right direction, I found more explicit instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429165/completely-uninstall-restore-textmate-2